# Using Amazons ElasticsearchService in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am in the process of setting up Elasticsearch for my Rails api. 
For starters, I set up Elasticsearch locally and had no trouble indexing and searching my DB using the [elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model)

Next, I want to use the AWS ElasticsearchService. I have set up the service and the domain in the AWS console following [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg.html).

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to connect to it. 
I have an AWS elasticsearch url and am trying to hit it, like so:

```
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4'

Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'https://search-my-cluster-abc123....es.amazonaws.com' do |f|
  f.request :aws_signers_v4,
            credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
            service_name: 'es',
            region: 'us-east-1'
end
```

I took this approach stragiht from elastic's github page [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-transport). However, I cannot seem to connect.

```
[1] pry(main)> Elasticsearch::Model.client.cluster.health
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: execution expired
```

I also looked over the Amazon Elasticsearch SDK, but it would appear that the SDK is only used to set up domains, not to perform the actual searches.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding an answer on the searchkik github shortly after I asked the question.

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/566

Make sure to preface your elasticsearch url with http://

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but using the new **faraday_middleware-aws-sigv4** gem. I found I could still use https but I needed to add the 443 port at the end of the URL:

```
require 'elasticsearch'
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_sigv4'

Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(url: 'https://search-my_elasticsearch_service.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com:443']) do |f|
  f.request :aws_sigv4,
    service: 'es',
    region: 'ap-southeast-2',
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
end
```